# How to make the NestedScrollView to be below the CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am new to android programming and am making a tour guide app and for the MainActivity , I have tried to implement an xml layout with CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView, however despite trying various solutions the scrollview still takes up the entire screen and i want the NestedScrollView to be the CollapsingToolbarLayout. How do I do that?

The xml layout of the activity_main.xml is given below and the image of the activity.

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/bangalore"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:elevation="6dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="1000dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviors">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/bengaluru_general_information"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/bengaluru_information"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/how_to_reach_bangalore"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/reach_bangalore_by_rail"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/information_on_how_to_reach_bangalore_by_rail"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/reach_bangalore_by_air"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/information_on_how_to_reach_bangalore_by_air"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and Image of the MainActivity
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfkVT.png)

Comment: Delete `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from everything and `android:minHeight="1000dp"` from `NestedScrollView`... See what happens

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: `AppBarLayout` has to have `CoordinatorLayout` as a parent and NOT `FrameLayout`, so, change your root layout to something else then `CoordinatorLayout` and change your `FrameLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: now the card views don't appear when i put the root layout as RelativeLayout or LinearLayout

Comment: Ok, i will stop guessing and just implement it in test app. Wait a minute.

Comment: Should I upload the Main activity.java file too

Comment: I dont think its necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, its scrappy, but it works, just dig into the code and change whatever parameters that you want and customize it to your liking:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="aaa"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="aaa"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="aaa"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="aaa"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="aaa"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```